# Show JavaScript alert in page div rather than pop up box

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have validation functions on a form that currently use alert to display a pop up box with the message:

HTML

```
<label for="password" >Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required>
<label for="password2" >Password:</label>
    <input type="password2" id="password2" name="password2" placeholder="confirm assword" required>

        <div class="error" id="error"></div>
```

JS

```
function confirmPassword() {
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value
    var password2 = document.getElementById("password2").value
        if(password != password2) {
            alert('You entered two different passwords, please make sure both password fields match.');
        }
}
```

How can I make the text that currently shows in a pop up box show in the `<div class="error" id="error"></div>` instead?

Comment: use div.innerHTML instead of alert();

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
 alert('You entered two different passwords, please make sure both password fields match.');
```

to

```
 document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = 'You entered two different passwords, please make sure both password fields match.';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change this:

```
alert('You entered two different passwords, please make sure both password fields match.');
```

to(as stated by Kevin P.):

```
document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "You entered two different passwords, please make sure both password fields match.";
```

OR using jquery(since you tagged jquery):

```
$("#error").html("You entered two different passwords, please make sure both password fields match.");
```

also, to avoid errors please use strict inequality signs:

```
if(x !== y){
    // some code here
}else{
    // some code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

document.getElementById("error").innerHTML = "You entered two different passwords, please make sure both password fields match.";

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
function showPopup(text, title) {
  $('#popup-body').empty();
  popup = $('#popup');
  popup.css("display", "block");
  $('#backdrop-div').css("display", "block");
  popupHead = $('#popup-header-text');
  popupHead.html(title);
  popupBody = $('#popup-body');
  popupBody.html(text);
}

function show() {
  showPopup($('#text').val(), $('#title').val());
}

(function() {
  $('#backdrop-div').click(function() {
    $('#popup').css("display", "none");
    $('#backdrop-div').css("display", "none");
  });
  $(document).keyup(function(event) {
    if ($('#popup').css("display") == "block") {
      if (event.which == 27) {
        $('#popup').css("display", "none");
        $('#backdrop-div').css("display", "none");
      }
    }
  });
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .popup-box {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    height: 200px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -100px;
    margin-left: -250px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 100000000;
    border: 2px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 15px;
  }
  .popup-header {
    margin-top: -19px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #000000;
    background: red;
    text-align: center;
    font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
    border-top-right-radius: 15px;
    border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  }
  .popup-body {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    height: 40px;
    background: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .popup-header-text {
    margin-top: 40px;
  }
</style>
<div id="backdrop-div" style="width: 1000%; height: 1000%; z-index: 20000; background-color: #000000; opacity: 0.3; top: 0; left: 0; position: fixed; display: none"></div>
<div id="popup" class="popup-box" style="display: none;">
  <div id="popup-header" class="popup-header">
    <h3 id="popup-header-text">Header</h3>
  </div>
  <div id="popup-body" class="popup-body">Text</div>
</div>

<div>
  Text:
  <textarea id="text">You entered two different passwords, please make sure both password fields match.</textarea>
  <br>Title:
  <input id="title" value="ERROR!!!">
  <br>
  <button onclick="show();">Show popup!</button>
</div>
```

However, instead of copying the code, you may want to change some things, like the CSS.